# Determine the Swift compiler version used to create a Framework

Tags: swift, xcode, clang, abi, mach-o

I want to know what compiler version was used exactly. In my example I tried the following:

```
otool -L TestFramework 
TestFramework:
    @rpath/TestFramework.framework/Versions/A/TestFramework (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1675.129.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)
    @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1103.8.25)
```

It looks like `1103.8.25` could be useful, but when I look the version up (on Wikipedia) it doesn't help, as the versions there look like this:

```
5.3 (swiftlang-1200.0.29.2 clang-1200.0.30.1),
5.3.1 (swiftlang-1200.0.41 clang-1200.0.32.8),
5.3.2 (swiftlang-1200.0.45 clang-1200.0.32.28)
etc..
```

It looks like that my `1103.8.25` might hint to one of these:

```
5.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.1 clang-1103.0.32.29),
5.2.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.6 clang-1103.0.32.51),
5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53),
5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53),
5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53)
```

, because of the `1103` but which one is it?

I am aware that I can check the `.swiftinterface` file if the binary has been compiled with ABI stability, but let's assume it hasn't been. How does Xcode do it?

Is there a list of `libswiftCore.dylib` versions somewhere that can be used for lookup?